# Computing relative error with ideal gas law.

Tags: physics, error-propagation

### Problem

I want to compute relative error for volume when i have measured following data.
$$
\left|
\begin{matrix}
\hline
\text{Measured data}\\
\hline
T=301.4\pm 0.1 \text{ K}\\
p=253.1\pm0.04 \text{ kPa} \\
\hline
\end{matrix}
\right|
\quad
\left|
\begin{matrix}
\hline
\text{Constants} \\
\hline
n=2.0 \text{ mol} \\
R=8.31447 \frac{\text{J}}{\text{K mol}} \\
\hline
\end{matrix}
\right|
$$
$$
\left|
\begin{matrix}
\hline
n=\text{amount of substance in gas(in moles)} \\
T=\text{The absolute temperature of gas} \\
p=\text{pressure of the gas} \\
V=\text{volume of the gas} \\
R=\text{gas constant} \\
\hline
\end{matrix}
\right|
$$
[wikipedia - Ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law)

### Attempt to solve:

A expression for volume in this case can be easily derived from ideal gas law

$$ pV=nRT $$
Expression for volume is:
$$ V=\frac{nRT}{p} $$

To my understanding we should be able to compute the relative error $\Delta V$ with partial differential equation:

$$ \Delta V = |\frac{\delta V}{\delta p}|\Delta p+ |\frac{\delta V}{\delta T}|\Delta T $$

$$ \Delta V =|-\frac{nRT}{p^2}|\Delta p + |\frac{nR}{p}|\Delta T$$

If we plug in the values

$$ \Delta V =|-\frac{2 \text{ mol}\cdot 8.31447 \frac{\text{J}}{\text{K mol}}\cdot 301.4 \text{ K}}{(253.1 \text{ kPa})^2}|\cdot0.04 + |\frac{2.0 \text{ mol}\cdot 8.31447 \frac{\text{J}}{\text{K mol}}}{253.1 \text{ kPa}}|\cdot0.1$$

$$ \Delta V \approx 9.699668356 \cdot 10^{-3} \text{ m}^3 $$
and in liters
$$ \Delta V \approx 9.699668356 \text{ L} $$

$$ \Delta V \approx 9.7 \text{ L} $$

---

For some unknown reason this isn't the correct answer to this problem. If someone can spot the error that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: See e.g. http://webpages.ursinus.edu/lriley/ref/unc/unc.html (Propagation of Uncertainties in Calculations ->  In General (Approximately))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get by 10^-6, not 10^-3 in Mathcad:

[image]